# Recover non-sent Voice Note on WhatsApp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, recovery-mode, audio-recording

I need to recover a non-sent audio on WhatsApp. I was keeping my phone hidden so the person threatening me wouldn't know I was recording and when I took my phone off my pocket, I accidentally clicked on "cancel". Is there anyway to recover it from WhatsApp database or Android?